# I can't click Webbrowser's Mobile Element

Tags: vb6

I want to click one  but I couldn't click it with my standard code. You need to press F12 and select mobile emulator to see this mobile version of website. After then you can click button manually but you can't click it programmatically. I can't use API so I need to do it with web elements.

This is my standard code;

```
For Each obj1 In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
            If (obj1.GetAttribute("class") = "_o5rm6 coreSpriteCameraInactive") Then
                obj1.Click: Exit For
            End If
            Next
```

This is the button where I want to click:

[image: Instagram]